# How to use DateTime.Now without error inside stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, entity-framework-core

I have problem into my Blazor Project, I use 'DateTime.Now' into my variables for insert it into my sql database with stored procedures. But I have this error message : 'Error converting data type varchar to datetime.'

I give you the stored procedure + code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNewLog] @Date datetime
AS
insert into dbo.LogChange (Date) values (@Date);
```

and the code :

```
LogModel l = new LogModel
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now,
            };
            await _logdb.NewLog(l);
```

I add _logdb.NewLog(LogModel log) :

```
string sql = "spNewLog @Date ='" + log.Date + "';"
            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql);
            }
```

Another edit : I use dapper

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is a property. The `DateTime` type maps to `datetime` without any problems. What does `NewLog` do? It looks like it's converting the date to a string instead of using a date parameter

Comment: I have edit in title, but I use in property in my code

Comment: What does that code do? ADO.NET won't convert a DateTime to a string. The code is doing something it shouldn't be doing. Are you using string interpolation to generate queries perhaps?

Comment: You need to show us how exactly the SP is executed. What does `_logDb.NewLog()` do?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with stored procedures. Please post `NewLog()`.

Comment: _logDb.NewLog() execute **ExecuteAsync("spNewLog @Date =" + l.Date)**

Comment: Don't do that. You converted the date to a localized string. In fact, since you probably use Dapper, you could use `connection.ExecuteAsync("spNewLog",new {date=l.date});`

Comment: @SoyNeko update the question with the relevant code please. Not just this snippet, the entire method. You may use Dapper or not, we can't guess

Comment: @SoyNeko you can't just append a `DateTime` to a string, which means `l.Date` is a string property that formats the DateTime using a localized format. There's no need to do this. Which data access library are you using?

Comment: It's good I have edit with the function

Comment: And in my model, Date is define with **public DateTime Date {get; set;} **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line :

```
string sql = "spNewLog @Date ='" + log.Date + "';"
```

generates and executes a string. The date is converted into a localized string that doesn't match the server's locale. There's no need to use such code.

It looks like the code is using Dapper, as there's no `ExecuteAsync` method in `IDbConnection`. Dapper was built to remove the need for string concatenations and make it easier to write parameterized queries.

The code can be changed to :

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await connection.ExecuteAsync("spNewLog",
                                   new {date=log.Date},
                                   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

**Consider using a logging library**

You could simplify your code a lot by using .NET Core's ILogger with a logging library. Most logging libraries can write to database tables.

For example, Serilog can write to SQL Server using the [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver). This would easier logging and collect a lot more information than just a date. Serilog has sinks for [Blazor client-side logging to the consol](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-browserconsole) or [sending the logs to the server](https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-browserhttp).